# Electric stopped working after I moved my microwave?

Tags: electrical, wiring

"We moved the microwave to a different spot in the kitchen and didn't realize the circuit wasn't large enough to support it. The whole wall quit working. We changed out the actual breaker in the breaker box but nothing happened.

When the breaker is on, our tester shows that there is electricity going to each outlet but nothing will come on when we plug it in.

Comment: Ok, are you sure the breaker in the panel tripped? Also, I can't recommend defaulting to changing out a breaker, *especially* since it seems like you probably upped the rating to make it "hold"; not good or correct!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me like an open neutral. This will give you a reading of voltage (to ground or with a pen tester) but the circuit will not work.

You need to check the connections at every device on the circuit.